# How can I get passenger-config restart-app to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, passenger, capistrano3

Rails 4.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 with rbenv and ruby 2.2.1.

Using capistrano with the capistrano-passenger gem, but the restart at the end fails:

```
INFO [8213c63a] Running /usr/bin/env passenger-config restart-app /home/deployer/my_app --ignore-app-not-running as deployer@mysite.com
DEBUG [8213c63a] Command: passenger-config restart-app
DEBUG [8213c63a]    Please pass either an app path prefix or an app group name. See --help for more information.
```

When I try to run this command at the command line via SSH, I get this:

```
    deployer@host:~/app/shared/config$ passenger-config restart-app
*** ERROR: You are not authorized to query the status for this
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm using Apache, here's the relevant parts of my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.5/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
     PassengerRoot /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.5
     PassengerDefaultRuby /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/ruby
   </IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName mysite.name.com
      # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
      DocumentRoot /home/deployer/myssite/current/public
      <Directory /home/deployer/mysite/current/public>
         # This relaxes Apache security settings.
         AllowOverride all
         # MultiViews must be turned off.
         Options -MultiViews
         # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
         Require all granted
      </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I just encountered the same issue (Ubuntu 14.04, Apache+mod_passwnger, Rbenv, Ruby 2.0.0p594, Rails 4.1, Capistrano 3.4.0). I am mid-figuring it out right now, but more info from you might help me troubleshoot your setup. Are you using Apache or nginx? If you are using Apache, can you show the DocumentRoot and Passenger* lines from your Apache config?

Answer (score 7):

Here's what got me running, I added this to my `conifg/deploy.rb`:

```
set :passenger_restart_with_sudo, true
```

Ref: https://github.com/capistrano/passenger/

To add password-less `sudo` access for the `deployer` user, on the server do:

(you might want to be more specific as to the allowed commands)

```
sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/deployer > /dev/null <<'EOF'
deployer ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
EOF
```

...and in your `delpoy.rb`, have:

```
set :user, 'deployer' # Deployment user on remote servers
```

**Note**: it should be noted that the Passenger authors are [working on a method so that sudo will not be required any longer](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1392) in the future.

Comment: This didn't help.  After adding it, I get:  `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`.  So, I added `default_run_options[:pty] = true`, but it still fails with the same error.

Comment: I have not been able to get Capistrano to actually work with using `sudo` passwords. You'll have to use password-less sudo for the deployer user. I kinda really hate that, it makes me feel kinda sick when I think about it. I intend to work on making a fix for this as soon as life gives me time to address it. I'll update my answer with the sudoers line needed.

Comment: It should be noted that we (the Passenger authors) are working on [a method so that sudo will not be required any longer](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1392) in the future.

Comment: Passenger 5.0.10 now has sudo-less restarts with passenger-config. setting :passenger_restart_with_sudo to false should work.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use `sudo` for restarting application server, simply add to `config/deploy.rb`:

```rb
namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end
end
```

For restarting with `sudo` (Note that it doesn't have any effect on Passenger < 5):

```
set :passenger_restart_with_sudo, false
```

If you want to change restarting options, you might override these:

```
set :passenger_restart_command, 'passenger-config restart-app'
set :passenger_restart_options, -> { "#{deploy_to} --ignore-app-not-running" }
```